# Using jQuery to control click events by adding/removing classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have something like this code running:

```
function blah() {
jQuery(".class1").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(this).text('Validate').addClass('class2').removeClass("class1");
   //more stuff here
    jQuery(".class2").on("click", function() {
           jQuery(this).removeClass("class1");
           //More stuff here
```

This is bad because the click events propagate, every click that occurs adds the click event multiple times. I tried closing off the first selector (like so) and having the click events seperately but the second click event never occurred(!):

```
function blah() {
jQuery(".class1").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(this).text('Validate').addClass('class2').removeClass("class1");
});
jQuery(".class2").on("click", function() {
           jQuery(this).removeClass("class1");
           //More stuff here
```

How do I structure code so that on the first click one thing happens, and the second click another thing happens without click events doubling

Comment: I kind of feel like you are trying to get help fixing a hack rather than the original problem you were having. Could you explain exactly what you are trying to do? That way we can actually provide better answers for you. Also, if you could provide a [fiddle](jsfiddle.net) demonstrating your issue - that would be helpful.

Comment: This is correct, I will provide a detailed explanation in the morning. I want to get better at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".class1", function() {
    jQuery(this).text('Validate').addClass('class2').removeClass("class1");
});
jQuery(document).on("click", ".class2", function() {
           jQuery(this).removeClass("class1");
           //More stuff here
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f3Nre/)